# how to make rigidbody slide on diagonal wall collision

Tags: unity-game-engine, game-physics, rigid-bodies

I'm struggling a lot with moving Rigidbodies, currently I have this method to move player:

```
private void SimpleMove()
        {
            var scaledMovementSpeed = movementSpeed;
            _isRunning = false;
            if (Run)
            {
                scaledMovementSpeed *= runMultiplier;
                _isRunning = true;
            }
            var trans = transform;
            var forward = trans.forward;
            var newDirection = Vector3.RotateTowards(forward, SimpleMoveVector, Time.fixedDeltaTime * rotationSpeed, 0.0f);
            trans.rotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(newDirection, trans.up);
            var velocity = _rigidbody.velocity;
            var velocityChange = new Vector3(forward.x * scaledMovementSpeed, velocity.y, forward.z * scaledMovementSpeed) - velocity;
            _rigidbody.AddForce(velocityChange, ForceMode.VelocityChange);
            _isMoving = true;
        }
```

Map is build out of simple cubes right now and the player has capsule collider on him with freeze rotation on all axes.
By tweaking force values a little bit I managed to get it to work properly without the need to check for collisions myself 
**but** 
expected behavior of player going diagonally into wall is to slide perpendicular to its surface. When I get close to cube's corner character slides across but when I'm going diagonally into a wall character just stops. Haven't tried it with analog input yet.
Is there a way to properly make character slide (fe. put proper physics material on him, or the wall?) or do I need to explicitly check and manage these collisions myself for that?
I thought that my turn-and-then-go-forward method might be messing with proper colliding, but I made the turn instant and the behavior was exactly the same.

Comment: Try adding a physics material with low friction to the wall collider. You shouldn't need to manage collisions manually. All that's typically needed is for this effect is for the character to have a collider and non-kinematic rigidbody and for the wall to have a collider with a physics material attached.

Comment: @Studwell thanks for advice. I set the dynamic friction to 0, doesn't work perfectly, because character sometimes slides ok and sometimes switches between stopping and sliding but it should be enough to make controls smoother